# making malloc function doesn't work correctly?

Tags: c, malloc

Hi i wrote a simple malloc and free function. The idea is basically from "The C Programming language". Now i have the problem like if I malloc 3 times and i free it in the same order. My allocp is near to the end but the whole memory is free. I give you my example now. My problem is with the 3 frees. Like when i free 4, 3, 2 its ok because you free the allocp down in the correct order, but i don't know how to solve my problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help :)

```
#include "mystdlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define ALLOCSIZE 1048576 /* Groeße des verfuegbaren Speichers */

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]; /* Speicher fuer mymalloc */
static char *allocp = allocbuf; /* next free position */

void *mymalloc(size_t size) {
    if(allocp + size <= allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE) {
        allocp += size;
        return (allocp - size);
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }

}

void myfree(void *ptr) {
    if(ptr >= (void*)allocbuf && ptr < (void*)allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE) {
        allocp = ptr;
    }
}
```

```
int main(){
    char *buf1 = mymalloc(900000);
    if (buf1 == NULL) {
        printf("Error 404, allocated memory not found...\n");
        return -1;
    }
    myfree(buf1);

    char *buf2 = mymalloc(500000);
    char *buf3 = mymalloc(400000);
    char *buf4 = mymalloc(300000);

    if (buf2 == NULL || buf3 == NULL) {
        printf("Fix your mymalloc!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (buf4 == NULL) {
        printf("This was supposed to happen. Very good!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Nope. That's wrong. Very wrong.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    myfree(buf2);
    myfree(buf3);
    myfree(buf4);

    char *buf5 = mymalloc(900000);
    if (buf5 == NULL) {
        printf("You got so far, but your error free journey ends here. Because an error occured.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char *buf6 = myrealloc(buf5, 500000);
    myfree(buf6);

    printf("Congrats, you passed all tests. Your malloc and free seem to work\n");
}
```

Comment: If you want to be able to free the memory in any order, then you need to implement your malloc/free functions differently with a less simplistic approach.

Comment: What is your problem, except freeing in the wrong order? If you want to free in any order, you have to rethink how you do your malloc. What you need is some sort of list of the free blocks. I can't go in more detail than that, since a complete answer is way beyond the scope of a stackoverflow question. But as soon as you have some code outlining your approach, you can begin starting questions about the details you have problem with.

Comment: Your simple approach would work if you call `myfree` in the reverse order of the corresponding `mymalloc` calls.

Comment: Your malloc function is not correct because the pointers returned are not aligned